# Missing column statistics in Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I recently migrated a SQL Server database from an on-premise SQL Server instance to Azure SQL and started noticing performance issues. I used [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to migrate the schema and data. The database is in an elastic pool.

For example, a stored procedure in Azure runs in over 1 minute, while on-premise it's almost instant. Same data and database structure (including indexes and foreign keys).

When comparing the execution plans between Azure and the on-premise server, the are a lot of differences. There are a lot of warnings related to missing column statistics, which seems to be the cause of the issue.

As far as I know, column statistics are created automatically by the db engine when that column is used in a JOIN or a WHERE clause. But this doesn't seem to be the case for this db.

I verified that the required settings "Auto Create Statistics" and "Auto Update Statistics" are turned on.

If I export a table schema and create a new table with a different name and the exact same structure, and then write a query with a `WHERE` clause, the column statistics are created instantly. But when running the exact same query on an existing table, the statistics are not created.

I could create the statistics manually for the current columns like it is described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151158/45756) but if a new column will be added to a table in the future, it might not be created. Just to check, I did create one column statistics manually for the stored procedure mentioned above and it worked, execution time dropped from >1 minute to 5 seconds.

What could be missing here, why aren't the statistics created automatically for existing tables?

Comment: Statistics are only created automatically if your settings are correct. You need to run 'alter database set auto_create_statistics on' for the database (google exact syntax).

Comment: I don't know how you have rebuild your statistics, but if there are no statistics then rebuild does not help. You can also create the statistics manually. Also make sure you have your indexes as before the migration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but statistics are being created now and the SP I mentioned above runs instantly.

I did rebuild statistics for indexes and primary keys a day before using this:

https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution

But it didn't seem to have any effect (maybe it had a delayed effect?). This is also listed as a migration recommendation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/migrate-to-database-from-sql-server#optimize-performance-after-the-migration-completes

Also, what I found is that not all columns should have column statistics. If a column is part of an index or a primary key, the statistics will be created for that object and there will be no separate statistics for that column.